# To add category filter in Product grid magento2

Tags: filter, magento2

I have tried to add Category column in Product grid admin area.I have added it successfully by below code.

```
<column name="category" class="Chilly\Productsgrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Chilly\Productsgrid\Model\Category\Categorylist</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

In Chilly\Productsgrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category.php, **prepareDataSource()** method

```
$fieldName = $this->getData('name');
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        //$categories=array();
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $p_id=$item['entity_id'];
            $product=$this->_productloader->create()->load($p_id);
            $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
            $objectManager   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $categories=array();
            if(count($cats) ){
                foreach($cats as $cat){
                    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat);
                    $categories[]=$category->getName();
                }

    }
    $item[$fieldName]=implode(',',$categories);
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
```

Got Categories list in product grid. I have tried the following code for add filter,

```
<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
```

and for add options to category filter dropdown,

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Chilly\Productsgrid\Model\Category\Categorylist</item>
```

category dropdown came in filter section. But not add categories list to category dropdown.

But i'm fearing, whether this is the right way to achieve my task or not!  could you tell me, is it right way and provide me  the solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed Catgeory filter issue by override **Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider** Ui file

Plz check the reference here : [Add Category filter to Product Grid in magento2](https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2016/11/29/add-category-filter-to-product-grid-in-magento2/)